# Thread - Multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to thread, I just wrote a simple program to understand the concept, This program gives me output as :

One
Four
Three
Back in main
Two
Master

```
public class Sample_thread{
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        Runnable m= new Master();
        Thread master =  new Thread(m);

        Runnable p1 = new one();
        Thread t1 =  new Thread(p1);    

        Runnable p2 = new two();
        Thread t2 =  new Thread(p2);

        Runnable p3 = new Three();
        Thread t3 =  new Thread(p3);

        Runnable process_4 = new Four();
        Thread t4 =  new Thread(p4);

        master.start();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        System.out.println("Back in main");     
    }   
}
```

I am printing the thread name in the run method of each thread. Why is the order changed in display??

I thought it will display like

Master
one
Two
Three
Four
Back in main

Can any one explain me this? Is this because I didn't mention synchronized??

Comment: What exactly do each of the threads do? Do they just print when run?

Answer (score 1):

This is the very behaviour that you get with concurrency. The threads run "at the same time", but the order is not defined.

You may want to have a read through the [Oracle Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using multiple threads is to execute largely independent actions which can occur in any order.  If you wanted the output in a set order, you would use a loop in one thread.